# Would there ever be a need to add ...IfExists operator to Condition Operators on 'AWS Global Condition Context Keys'?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-policies

**Would there ever be a need to add ...IfExists operator to Condition Operators on 'AWS Global Condition Context Keys'?**

AWS Global Condition Context Keys are available in every request context. AWS documentation states that:

> If you use condition keys that are available only in some
>   circumstances, you can use the IfExists versions of the condition
>   operators.

However, the example provided in AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html) seems to contradict the intended use of ..IfExists operator because they have added ...IfExists operator to Condition Operators on 'AWS Global Condition Context Keys'. I have put a screenshot of the example from AWS documentation - see below.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To use AWS condition keys, is it mandatory that they are present in the Request Context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61848301/to-use-aws-condition-keys-is-it-mandatory-that-they-are-present-in-the-request)

Comment: Thanks @ mokugo-devops - It was me who asked the question in the link but this is different although related - The question I have asked here is very specific to the usage of ..Ifexists clause & I feel AWS has given a contradicting example in their documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the "global" in `AWS Global Condition Context Keys` means that the scope of these condition keys is global. It doesn't mean these condition keys will all be present at once in every request. That's why each global condition key has availability information.